# RAI in D for structs, avoiding expensive copying

Tags: constructor, resources, destructor, d

I am a novice in D programming language. I am going to write some bindings of a C library in D. So this question.

Suppose we have a struct `S` (not class!)

Suppose all of the following are expensive operations:

- `S` initialization (constructor);
- `S` finalization (destructor);
- `S` postblit.

Now I want to pass `S` values around like this:

```
S func(const ref S x) {
    return S(x);
}
```

Question: Will excessive (more than minimally enough to express my algorithm) use of the above expensive operations happen? If yes, how to prevent this?

Note that I use struct rather than class from practical performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program shows that excessive copying does happen:

```
$ ./init_test 
Initialization
Postblit
Finalization
Finalization
```

Program text:

```d
import std.stdio;

struct Expensive {
    static create() {
        writeln("Initialization");
        return Expensive.init;
    }
    ~this() {
        writeln("Finalization");
    }
    this(this) {
        writeln("Postblit");
    }
}
    
Expensive func(const Expensive x) { // `ref const` results in compilation error
    return x;
}
    
void main() {
    Expensive obj = func(Expensive.create());
}
```

Comment: There is a DIP(improvement proposal) on his final stage to make D accept r-values on ref parameters, that possibly solve this issue.